# Maven plugin not found in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

In my pom.xml I get the following error:

```
Plugin '''org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.4''' not found less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspects a Maven model for resolution problems.
```

At the specific place:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId> <--- here, red text
    <version>2.10.4</version> <--- version number is also in red text
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadoc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I looked in my `.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/` and the directory maven-javadoc-plugin doesn't exist.

I tried `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` but it's still not downloading.

Comment: when you mean red text, it's about your IDE, right? Does it work via console?

Comment: @A_Di-Matteo In my case yes, `mvn javadoc:javadoc` seemed to work.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to force the downloads using `mvn clean -U package` via Commandline?

Comment: It didn’t seem to make any difference in my case.